# I can't seem to figure out how to make a dynamic search function

Tags: spreadsheet

=QUERY(Database!A6:I, "SELECT B,C WHERE B CONTAINS '"&A5&"' or C CONTAINS '"&A5&"'") isn't working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUJrp.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5biNz.png)

I tried all sorts of thigns that were online, I'm looking to make a sort of dynamic search function.